# Inno Setup CloseApplications during Uninstall?

Tags: inno-setup, inno-setup-v6

The `CloseApplications` [Setup] value seems to work fine.  But during uninstall, I don't get the same in-use message with option to kill them.  Instead it just schedules a reboot.  The File source line uses both `uninsrestartdelete` and `restartreplace`, since it works on setup, why not on the uninstall?

TIA!!

Comment: IIRC the uninstall executable does not use the Windows Restart Manager APIs.

Comment: shoot, is there a way to do it?  be a cleaner way to do it.